# Displaying image from database in TableView bugs

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a TableView and I am filling it with data retrieved from database. Everything works fine except the images. Because of the cell reuse behaviour, and I am fetching image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I chose to fetch images in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because in the details retrieving function (which is triggered in `viewDidLoad`), I need to do another request, which is causing other problems (reloading tableview before storing image url)

The problem is that when I scroll fast, the resuable cells bugs while displaying user images

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchData()
}

var theUser = 

func fetchData() {
   //.. after data is retrieved

   var innerDict = [String:String]()

   if let user = details.value![key] {
      if let name = user["name"] {
         // works
         innerDict["name"] = name
       }

      if let image = user["imageName"] {
       // gets the image name but at this point I need to;
       // a) retrieve the url here (with another call), which will eventually fail
       // to catch up with `innerDict` so `innerDict` won't contain `image` variable.
       // ie;

       myRef.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in }

      // b) Store the `image` name in innerDict and download image from url 
      // in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I chose this method:

        innerDict["image"] = image
      }

   user[id] = innerDict
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now the tableView as usual.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = ...

   // more stuff

   if let imageName = user["image"] {
      let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
      let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("gs://bucket.com").child(user[id]).child(imageName)

      storageRef.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
           if (error != nil) {
              // handle 
           } else {
              // I thought using Haneke would help to cache the image
               cell.image.hnk_setImage(URL!)
           }
      }
 }
```

This is the closest one I could reach. However images bug on displaying when I scroll fast.

---

**Edit:**

I also tried using this approach but it's downloading the same image multiple times with this method, so it takes time for the same images to displayed.

```
islandRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    let image: UIImage! = UIImage(data: data!)
    cell.userImage.hnk_setImage(image, key: "\(userID)")
  }
}
```

However, with top approach the speed was very fast. The only problem of the above code was the glitch when I scroll fast.

---

**Edit 2**

```
 var images = [UIImage]()

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemDetailTableViewCell

let item = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

if let uid = item["owner"] as? String {
   if let user = users[uid] {
      if let imageName = user["image"] { 
         if let img: UIImage = images[indexPath.row] {    // crash here "fatal error: Index out of range"
           cell.userImage.image = img
          }
      } else {
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("gs://bucket").child(uid).child(imageName)

        storageRef.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
           if (error != nil) {

            } else {
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                     cell.userImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(URL!)
                     self.images[indexPath.row] = cell.image.image!
               })
           }
         }
    }   
}





}
```

Comment: this happens because you always load images from the web, you should save images in the first time and show when scrolling

Comment: So do you suggest me to download the images as NSData and store them in a different array? Which place is the most appropriate for downloading + saving image?

Comment: Yeah, this glitch happens because you download image every time when cell is going to resuse

Comment: But there is a problem with that approach. As the image download would be a different asynchronous task, `tableView.reload()` would be triggered before the download of image succeeds. This would end up not showing images, am I wrong?

Comment: This bug occurs because you are not caching images. Try using a framework like SDWebImage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save images from url and show images when the cell is going to reuse, hopefully this will fix your glitch

```
 var myImages =  [String: UIImage]()


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemDetailTableViewCell
     let item = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    if let img: UIImage = myImages["\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)"] {
        cell.image.image = img
    } else {
      if let uid = item["owner"] as? String {
        if let imageName = user["image"] {
           let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
           let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("gs://bucket.com").child(user[id]).child(imageName)
           storageRef.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
               if (error != nil) {
                  cell.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder") // put default Image when failed to download Image
               } else {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                   cell.image.hnk_setImage(URL!)
                   // Store the image in to our cache
                   self.myImages["\(indexPath.section)\(indexPath.row)"]= cell.image.image
                })
              }
         }
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: The thing is, I was using Firebase Storage, I think I need to retrieve the url with a different request; and then perform download process (like `a)`). Or use [this method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_in_memory) to directly download. However, for the second option, I couldn't figure out how to put it in background thread. Can you please guide me? I'd be grateful

Comment: Ok try now :) , I 've fixed this according to firebase

Comment: Thanks for your time. But how did you get the `cell.image` ? It forces me to unwrap and then gives me `nil` error

Comment: `self.myImages[indexPath.row]= cell.image`. It should be `cell.image.image` if you want to keep `myImages` as `[UIImage]`, but it still throws the error. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil.. I think you stored in `myImages` and didn't use it in return also

Comment: Opzz my bad , your UIImage name wage image, that was not a good name for a UIImagew :D, Fixed, check now

Comment: Now another error on: `if let img: UIImage = myImages[indexPath.row] {` "fatal error: Index out of range" :/

Comment: Are you loading only one image ?

Comment: No, but there are similar ones. But I believe it's crashing on the first go, before even reaching inside its if

Comment: Please show you whole table view cellForRowAtIndexPath code, By the way according to your code you do not get indexPath.row to get multiple images or images name so I think you download only one image, hence I've again updated my code, Have a look :)

Comment: I also added a second edit in my question showing the latest version of my code. taking a look to yours now. Edit: You have changed it to only one image. I have multiple images, just same image for different row

Comment: Please Update your Original code , I mean All the lines :)

Comment: This is pretty much all; except getting username from array and displaying it on cell with the same method. With the error `fatal error: Index out of range`, I think this method could be a solution, but as it is empty in the beginning, it's giving this error I think. What do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114823/discussion-between-chathuranga-silva-and-senty).

Comment: Check now , please copy the exact code, earlier time you didn't copy the same code :)